# Dynamic Selection Method of QDataTable quasar-framework vue-js

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a list of collapsible’s in a v-for, and a QDataTable component inside with multiple selection as below.

```
<q-collapsible :label="req.label" v-for="(req, index) in requisitions" :key="index" class="collapsible-no-padding requisitionContainer" @open="openRequisition('Requisition' + req.reqId)" @close="closeRequisition('Requisition' + req.reqId)" :id='"Requisition" + req.reqId'>
  <q-list>
    <q-item link class='ordersContainer'>
      <q-item-main>
        <q-data-table
          :data="req.filteredOrdersList"
          :config="orderConfigs"
          :columns="orderColumns"
          @selection="selectOrders">
        </q-data-table>
      </q-item-main>
    </q-item>
  </q-list>
</q-collapsible>
```

It looks like this

[image]

However, since there are more than one table, if a selection is made on any of the tables, it does call the selection method with the selected item, but I have no way to tell which table it is a part of. This is a problem when a selection is removed and you are returned an empty array, for which I need to distinguish between each tables selection event. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why not pass the `req` to the `selectOrders` method?

Comment: Yeah, already tried it. So, the event handler pass the list of selected items as an argument to selectOrders. If I add an argument req, it overrides the default handler and I only get the req in selectOrders and not the selected list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the reference to the `req` object to the method in the `@selection` handler.

Since you also need the reference to the array of selected items currently being implicitly passed to the `selectOrder` method, you'll now need to explicitly pass that value. Normally, you could do that via the `$event` variable accessible inline.

However, contrary to [the documentation](http://quasar-framework.org/components/datatable.html#Vue-Events), the `<q-data-table>` component's `selection` event is emitting two variables: the count of the elements in the array of selected items, and the array of selected items itself, in that order.

To get a reference to the array of selected items, you'll need to access the second argument being emitted via `arguments[1]`:

```
@selection="selectOrders(arguments[1], req)"
```

Comment: seems to work, just one thing. So selection handler calls the method with 2 arguments (count_selection, selection_array). What do I add as the second attribute after $event?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Only the `selection` array is passed, not the count. http://quasar-framework.org/components/datatable.html#Vue-Events. If you want the length of the `selection` array just do `selection.length` in your method.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case if you're calling the method like in your example. And again, why would you even need the count, since you could simply do `selection.length`?

Comment: I know right, but just putting "selectOrders" in @selection calls the method with these arguments

Comment: On putting @selection="selectOrders($event, ref)" this is what I get in selectOrders method. https://ibb.co/fUHoAb

Comment: So what I need is, how can the second and perhaps third emitted arguments saved be accessed.

Comment: No problem. Me too!